# ¿Como sumo datos de un hijo en firebase con android studio (java).?

Tags: java, firebase, filtro, nodos

Les explico que quiero realizar, tengo un apartado con nombre de usuario, y además tiene un campo númerico que quiero sumar si cumple ciertas condiciones el  los demas datos de los nodos padre, quiero hacer una sumatoria de ese campo en especifico mientras cumpla: que el nombre de usuario sea el que se selecciono en un spinner y la fecha sea la seleccionada en el edittext con un datepicker.
quiero que me realice la sumatoria con estos filtros, he buscado información para sumar datos en firebase pero no he encontrado mucho.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que intentaste hasta el momento ?

Comment: Ya lo solucione use un for para recorrer el datasnapshot mientras el objeto sea igual a los filtros que le coloco con ifs dentro del for